# canvas.drawCircle draw nothing

Tags: java, android, view, draw

This is my view for drawing :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
    canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2,100, locationPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2,300, locationPaint);
    //canvas.drawRect(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2,100,100, locationPaint);
}

public void drawCircle(float centerX, float centerY, float width, float height){
    int ratio = 10;
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX/ratio,centerY/ratio,width/ratio,circlePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2,200, locationPaint);
}
```

But when i call drawCircle, it didn't draw nothing on the view, i don't know why... Do you know if i have to call onDraw somewhere ?

Comment: "don't call us, we will call you" - `onDraw` is called by a system, not you

Comment: The two first canvas.drawCircle are drawing. It's the draws in drawCircle function that not draw

Comment: is your `locationPaint` properly initialized? is it has eg. color set?

Comment: please, dont call any canvas related methods outside `onDraw` method

Comment: Ok pskink, but then tell me how i can draw things in real time

Comment: what is your paint like?

Comment: how do you call `drawCircle`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth/2, this.getHeight/2, 100, locationPaint();
    canvas.drawCircle(this.getWidth()/2,this.getHeight()/2,300, locationPaint);
}
```

Delete your drawcircle method that you made.
I don't think that you need super.onDraw() [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068354/do-i-need-to-call-back-super-ondraw-in-a-custom-view)
You don't need this.canvas = canvas;